# can't adapt type 'Point' in Django postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model called vehicle and a trip is associated with it.

```
    class Trip(models.Model):
        trip_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
        distance_unit = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        distance = models.FloatField(default=0)
        duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        dir_points = ArrayField(models.PointField(srid=4326,null=True), blank=True, null=True)
```

Now when ever I am trying to add new geometric points to this trip model it says "can't adapt type 'Point'". I have searched google alot for way around but all in vain. Can you please help me out here... How can I append new geometric points to this arrayfield. Please let me know if you need other information.
I am using django version 1.8 and python version 2.7.6.

Comment: What is your database ENGINE in the settings.py file?

Comment: did the answer given solved your problem.

Comment: @doru          I am using postgresql as database engin

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
A.geoCoords = GEOSGeometry('POINT(LAT LON)', srid=4326)
```

For detailed information [see](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#what-is-geos)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#what-is-geos

Comment: where lat and lon mean latitude and longitude, respectively and srid is optional, indicating the Spatial Reference System Identifier. Also I've added the link in the answer.